# How to merge two datasets in python

Tags: python, dataset

I have 1 dataset

```
NotesData = [{"Labels" : "Q1-17" , "EPCCO" : "This is Eppco Note" , "QACCO" : "This is QACCO Notes"}]
```

I have another datset

```
ChartData = [ {'ForDate': '2020-12-31T00:00:00', 'ForYear': 2020, 'Labels': 'Q1-17', 'EPCCO': 29.459162790697675, 'QACCO': 20.10097777777778}]
```

I want to see if the label of any object present in both datasets than i want to add all the keys in 2nd datasets from first datasets except Labels

For Example My Data would look like this

```
[ {'ForDate': '2020-12-31T00:00:00', 'ForYear': 2020, 'Labels': 'Q1-17', 'EPCCO': 29.459162790697675, 'QACCO': 20.10097777777778  , 'EPCCO_Note' : 'This is Eppco Note' , 'QACCO_Note' : 'This is QACCO Notes'}]
```

I can afford to loop on my first dataset because there will not be much objects , but I can not afford to loop on my second data sets as the data is too large it can be thousand of objects. and the keys EPPCO AND QACCO is dynamic so it can be any key .

Comment: and what if one object from `NotesData` contains a label which is presented in multiple objects in `ChartData`, How can you not loop on 2nd dataset then?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest This is  not the case  multiple objects can not have same labels in chartdata

Comment: you will inevitably start a loop when doing any traversal on  `ChartData`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried this solution it is working fine  , is there any thing I'm missing which can cause any problem ?

```
for note in NotesData: 
     matching_rows = [row for row in new_dataset if row['Labels'] == note['Labels']]
     if matching_rows:
      chart_row = matching_rows[0]  # Get the first matching row (assuming there's only one)
      keys_to_add = [key for key in note.keys() if key != 'Labels']
     for key in keys_to_add:
      chart_row[key+'_Note'] = note[key]
```

Comment: Looks like naive implementation of inner join. Replace `new_dataset` with `ChartData`.

Answer (score 0):

Using `pandas` is the out-of-box solution.

```py
import pandas as pd
Notes = pd.DataFrame(NotesData)
Chart = pd.DataFrame(ChartData)
Merged = Notes.merge(Chart, on=['Labels'])
```

Btw., pandas is an external package you have to install.

```bash
pip install pandas
```

Implementing from scratch requires iterating through both datasets. Thousands of elements should not be a problem, as long as it fits in your RAM.